# Is there a way to store a slash in a filename?

Tags: fat32, ext, fat16

Is there a way to have a slash "/" in a filename? The "real" slash, not some other Unicode symbol. The file system should be FAT16/32 and Ext4.

Comment: If you could, how would you use it? How would you say you want to open the file "a/b" rather then the file "b" in a directory "a"?

Comment: Escape it whit a backslash like for other special characters. It works for * and ?... Example: "a\/b"

Comment: That doesn't actually help. How would you tell whether "a\/b" meant the file "a\/b" or the file "b" in the directory "a\"? A backslash is a legal character in a filename. It's impossible in principle to have something that's a directory separator but also allow every possible sequence in a file name. Some sequence must be prohibited in a file name in order to be unambiguously used as a directory separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### ext4

No. ext4 allows all Unicode characters except NUL and `/`. The latter can't be used because it is the file system's directory separator.

#### FAT16/32

FAT16/32 doesn't support `/` natively, but long filenames (LFN) do.

However, the LFN drivers in Windows, Linux, Unix, MS-DOS, OS/2 and possibly other operating systems do **not** allow `/` to be part of a LFN. Even if you could create such a file with a different OS, you most likely wouldn't be able to access it using those operating systems.

Source: [Comparison of file systems - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems)

Comment: `> FAT doesn't support / natively, but long filenames (LFN) do.`   Huh‽ Where does it say that FAT supports `/`? `o.O`     `> Even if you could create such a file with a different OS, you most likely wouldn't be able to access it using those operating systems.`   That’s correct. I have done experiments in the past where I used a hex-editor to directly modify filenames in directory entries and while I could *view* directory listings, DOS and Windows (and of course programs) usually balked at anything that contained illegal characters. Some could still be renamed using wildcards, some could not.

Comment: @Synetech: I said that FAT does **not** support `/`. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You said that `/` can be used in long-filenames, but I have never seen anything to that effect. LFNs (i.e., vFAT) supports a few characters that plain FAT does not like `+` and `"`, but last I checked, `/` is not one of them. Were you referring to a file-system plug-in or something?

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article I linked to, VFAT LFN supports all Unicode characters except NUL. But that probably refers to the current specification (I can't find it), so this claim would be true if if there wasn't an actual implementation that supports all those characters.

Comment: @Synetech after some errors on a FAT 32 file, I now have a file whit a slash in its name (but sadly completely unrelated to where I want to have it in the first place). And yes, I can't do any thing whit it. That includes I can't delete it. How did you edit the directories whit a hex-editor?

Comment: `According to the Wikipedia article I linked to, VFAT LFN supports all Unicode characters except NUL.`   FAT32 does not support slashes, colons, asterisk ,etc. You are misinterpreting what it means: it supports *Unicode* characters like Chinese characters, Arabic letters, box-drawing, etc., not illegal characters which are used for file-system delimiters. It is certainly possible to accidentally/manual create such filenames, but they will not be readable by anything (OS, programs, etc.) that support the FAT spec.

Comment: @Den, have you tried using a wildcard instead? For example if your filename is `foo/bar.txt`, try using a command like `ren foo*.txt blah.txt` or `del foo?bar.txt`

Comment: @Synetech: The [FAT32 specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463080.aspx) doesn't specifically allow those characters, but it doesn't prohibit them either. So I regard filenames containing thosde characters the same way as device names (e.g., lpt1): prohibited by the OS, not the file system. I created files  (with `dd` and a hex editor) containing colons and slashes. Windows can access both files using their short name. Ubuntu even handles the colon in the GUI, but obviously chokes on the slash.

Comment: @Synetech: Yes, I tried stuff like that. I always get "No such file or directory"

Comment: @Den: Does the file have the slash in its 8.3 filename? If it doesn't, execute `dir /x` to see the short filename (e.g., `foobar~1.baz`) and use it to delete the file.